# SQL - Choosing a single record for an Id based on an attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a shirt table. There are multiple records for each Id (multiple brands). The Material will be same for the Id. The materials have a ranking association with Brand.

Material Ranking:
Cotton: Jockey > Nike > Adidas

Any other Material: Adidas > Nike > Jockey

For my result, I want to select only 1 record per Id based on the above ranking.
If the Id has cotton, I want the Jockey record to be chosen if Jockey is present, or if Jockey isn't there Nike must be chosen, if Nike also isn't there Adidas must be chosen.

For any other material, the second ranking should be followed.

Shirt table:

| Id | Brand | Material | Color | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nike | Cotton | Black | 500 |
| 1 | Jockey | Cotton | Blue | 100 |
| 1 | Adidas | Cotton | Red | 1000 |
| 2 | Jockey | Synthetic | Orange | 20 |
| 2 | Nike | Synthetic | Green | 2 |
| 3 | Nike | Cotton | Black | 500 |
| 4 | Nike | Wool | Black | 600 |
| 4 | Jockey | Wool | Blue | 20000 |
| 4 | Adidas | Wool | Red | 1000 |

Result:

| Id | Brand | Material | Color | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jockey | Cotton | Blue | 100 |
| 2 | Nike | Synthetic | Green | 2 |
| 3 | Nike | Cotton | Black | 500 |
| 4 | Adidas | Wool | Red | 1000 |

Explanation:
Result table Records have been chosen as per the ranking.
Since Id 1 has cotton, the Jockey record has been chosen.
Since Id 2 does not have cotton, the Nike record has been chosen (as per the ranking)
Since Id 3 has cotton, but does not have a Jockey record, the next rank has been chosen.
Since Id 4 does not have cotton, the Adidas record has been chosen.

Comment: where is rankings table

Comment: Try using a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression to generate an suitable ranking value. Let us know how you fare and we'll help you from there.

Comment: IMHO, using case for rankings is not very realistic. In real life it is highly probable OP would have brands more than just Jockey, Nike and Adidas.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `top(1) with ties`

```
select top(1) with ties *
from tbl
order by row_number() over(partition by id  
    order by
        case Material when 'Cotton' then 
           case Brand when 'Jockey' then 1 
                      when 'Nike' then 2 
                      when 'Adidas' then 3 end
        else 
           case Brand when 'Adidas' then 1 
                      when 'Nike' then 2
                      when 'Jockey' then 3 end
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ranking over (Brand, Material) with a `CASE` expression, then you can compare this field with the best ranking, obtainable using the `MIN` window function. Hence retrieve the rows where `ranking = best_ranking`:

```
SELECT Id,
       Brand,
       Material,
       Color,
       Cost
FROM (SELECT tab.*,
             CASE WHEN Brand = 'Jockey' AND Material =  'Cotton' THEN 1 
                  WHEN Brand = 'Nike'                            THEN 2
                  WHEN Brand = 'Adidas' AND Material <> 'Cotton' THEN 1
                                                                 ELSE 3
             END AS ranking,
             MIN(CASE WHEN Brand = 'Jockey' AND Material =  'Cotton' THEN 1 
                      WHEN Brand = 'Nike'                            THEN 2
                      WHEN Brand = 'Adidas' AND Material <> 'Cotton' THEN 1
                                                                     ELSE 3
                 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS best_ranking  
      FROM tab    ) ranked_brands
WHERE ranking = best_ranking
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2aa2e5c9adfe71386f3171f90b2df4c9).

Comment: <pedantry> Your code contains `case` _expressions_. Where is this `case` _statement_ to which you refer? SQL Server doesn't have one. </pedantry>

Comment: pedantry yes, but it's more correct referring to `case` *expression*, I'll update right away, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in real life you would have more than 3 brands, a rankings table would be feasible to use.

```
DECLARE @Rankings TABLE
(
    Material VARCHAR(10),
    Brand VARCHAR(10),
    Ranking INT
);
INSERT @Rankings
(
    Material,
    Brand,
    Ranking
)
VALUES
('Cotton', 'Jockey', 1),
('Cotton', 'Nike', 2),
('Cotton', 'Adidas', 3),
(NULL, 'Adidas', 1),
(NULL, 'Nike', 2),
(NULL, 'Jockey', 3);

DECLARE @Items TABLE
(
    Id INTEGER,
    Brand VARCHAR(6),
    Material VARCHAR(9),
    Color VARCHAR(6),
    Cost INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO @Items
(
    Id,
    Brand,
    Material,
    Color,
    Cost
)
VALUES
(1, 'Nike', 'Cotton', 'Black', 500),
(1, 'Jockey', 'Cotton', 'Blue', 100),
(1, 'Adidas', 'Cotton', 'Red', 1000),
(2, 'Jockey', 'Synthetic', 'Orange', 20),
(2, 'Nike', 'Synthetic', 'Green', 2),
(3, 'Nike', 'Cotton', 'Black', 500),
(4, 'Nike', 'Wool', 'Black', 600),
(4, 'Jockey', 'Wool', 'Blue', 20000),
(4, 'Adidas', 'Wool', 'Red', 1000);

WITH ordered
AS (SELECT i.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.Id ORDER BY r.Ranking) orderId
    FROM @Items i
        INNER JOIN @Rankings r
            ON i.Brand = r.Brand
               AND
               (
                   (
                       r.Material = i.Material
                       AND i.Material = 'Cotton'
                   )
                   OR
                   (
                       r.Material IS NULL
                       AND i.Material <> 'Cotton'
                   )
               ))
SELECT ordered.Id,
       ordered.Brand,
       ordered.Material,
       ordered.Color,
       ordered.Cost
FROM ordered
WHERE ordered.orderId = 1;
```